# Cant display JSON data in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm working on an API App utilizing the Foursquare API. Using my **getRequest**,
Im getting my results in **JSON**, which Im displaying in my *console*.log.

The thing is, I don't know how to parse the **JSON data** and display what I want on my **HTML page**.

I'm trying to have the **'name'** of the venues displayed, but I don't know how to do it.

P.S: I have a ***Math.random*** function on the incoming data from Foursquare, so whatever random venue name that is displayed in my  console.log is what I want displayed in my HTML page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Search</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" id="jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apps/app.js"></script>

</head>

    <body>

        <H1>Hunger Pains</H1>
            <p>Search for food cause you cant take it anymore</p>

            <!--This is the area your location gets spit out on the html page-->
            <p id="demo"></p>

            <form id ="search-term">

            <!--text entry field-
            <input type="text" id="query">-->

            <!--Submit button-->
            <input id="submit" type="submit"  value="submit">

            <!--Search results div-->
            <div id="search-results"></div>


            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;

//When you click the submit button it fires off the getRequest.
$(function(){
  $('#search-term').submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //getRequest();
        myFunction();


  });
});

// This is the get request. It has a random function that randomizes the callback data. Once you get the randomizes data, it shows in the console window.
//This function displays three random results based on the myFunction below
function getRequest(){

  $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?v=20131016&ll=40.7%2C-74&intent=browse&radius=800&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=C2IEUINHBL2HEVOHIWNO0GGN5EUHK3PGYH03HCZRP2ETA4CF&client_secret=DOLF3UBQZOY5GX2DP3EXBQ5CW4AHEWMNDGRMH0IHJWZBDSIO', function(data){
    var random = data.response.venues[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.response.venues.length)];
    //showResults();
    console.log(random);

    });

}

//This is the function that calls getRequest function three times then stops.

  function myFunction(){
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){getRequest();}, 500);
    //clearTimeout(myVar);
    setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( myVar); }, 1600);
}

});
```

Comment: Just guessing, but probably `random.name`.

Comment: The 'O' in JSON is for Object. You get an object back, and it has properties so you can use it exactly like @Barmar suggests. You can replace your `console.log(random)` with `console.log(random.name)` to print out the random business's name.

Comment: Awesome! That totally worked. Such a simple answer and Ive been racking my brain over this. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
$("#search-results").append('<br>' + random.name);
```

Comment: Just realized something. My console displays 3 objects. When I use: $("#search-results").text(random.name); my HTML page only displays one venue name. How can I get it to display all three at the same time?

Comment: I've changed the answer to use `append` so it doesn't replace the old contents of the result DIV.

Answer (score 1):

To get the name from the object you are getting from Foursquare use:

`console.log(random.name);`

And if you need the url for example use:

`console.log(random.url);`